# how can i limit outgoing emails in postfix server?

Tags: postfix, email, quota

I want to implement quota in postfix on all outgoing mails on user base with few exceptions.

My setup is something like this

SMTP Server 1 ( basic spam protection)  ---->   mail gateway(To have full av/spam scan) ----->   original server

Now all the outgoing mails will be relayed from original server,which will in turn handled by mail gateway and will be released by SMTP1 server. (However all are having valid FQDN and mx/A records.)

i want to configure mail gateway in such a manner that no user will able to send more than configured emails on per hour and per day basis. (Say max 100 mails per hour,and max 1000 mails per day)
can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Policyd](http://www.policyd.org/tiki-index.php?page=homepage).

Comment: Hi Janne,Thanks for your reply but its in accounting module as TODO list
as of now it is not available
:(
i have checked it in 2.0.10 version.
please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I'm using that module just like you described. At the moment I'm unable to provide you an example, but will do that right after I get back to work :)